# Merge two tables having one column partially in common

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table and, joining them, I obtain some particular records but I would like to add one column to the obtained query;
these are the tables in question

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UODjL.png)

This is the code that I use

```
select a.uniqueid,null as uni,b.freetxt,b.free
from (select distinct uniqueid from uniqueid_5) a
inner join freetxt_5 b
on a.uniqueid=b.freetxt or b.freetxt like a.uniqueid+'[ -]%'
```

Now I would like to add one column (uni)to the table obtained, adding the records that are still in the table uniqueid_5 but with join I add more records than what I need.

Comment: What do you mean by  with join I add more records than what I need ? you can post some sample data and explain

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your query returned more rows than expected.
In this particular case, returning the `uni` column will "invalidate" the `distinct` or better said it won't work the way you wanted it to as it will now return only **UNIQUE PAIRS OF UNIQUEID AND UNI** which in return will get you more rows returned.

For every `uniqueid` 'a' in `unique_5` the query will return all rows from `freetxt_5` that contain 'a' or 'a - 1' in the `freetxt` column.

Comment: yep,you clarify the problem; i dont know how to solve it

Comment: You need to find another way to join those tables, since there is nothing in common to join the second column `uni` on. The data you have above does not allow any way to create the output you want.